# ClassDefNotFoundError while class in classpath

Tags: java, classpath, antlr, antlr3, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to run [ParSeMiS](https://www2.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/EN/research/ParSeMiS/index.html). According to the documentation, it requires `ant`, `prefuse` and `antlr` jars to be available in its `lib` directory. I've put all the required jars in it. However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/TokenStreamException
    at de.parsemis.miner.environment.Settings.parseFileName(Settings.java:198)
    at de.parsemis.miner.environment.Settings.parseOption(Settings.java:312)
    at de.parsemis.miner.environment.Settings.parse(Settings.java:170)
    at de.parsemis.miner.environment.Settings.parse(Settings.java:122)
    at de.parsemis.Miner.run(Miner.java:358)
    at de.parsemis.Miner.main(Miner.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.TokenStreamException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 6 more
```

Now, I've verified that `antlr/TokenStreamException.class` is present in the `antlr` jar. I have tried adding the jar manually to the classpath by both exporting the `CLASSPATH` variable and setting it via the `-cp` switch. However, none of that works, and I still get this exception. Can anybody help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: How are you running your app?

Comment: please provide what you have in `WEB-INF/lib` folder. You are missing jar files...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using the following command to run the jar: `java -jar parsemis-2008-12-01.jar --graphFile=graph.dot --minimumFrequency=4`.

Comment: @FahimParkar err this is not a web application. I have a lib directory with the contents: `ant.jar`, `antlr-3.4-complete.jar` and `prefuse.jar`.

Comment: @KG: Okay, I thought that might be it - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `-jar` which ignores your CLASSPATH environment variable. You should list your dependencies in the manifest, [as shown here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), e.g.

```
Class-Path: lib/ant.jar lib/antlr-3.4-complete.jar lib/prefuse.jar
```

(It *should* have still worked with an explicit `-cp` option, however. My guess is that you got something wrong when specifying that, and assumed it was the same underlying cause as the failure when using the environment variable.)

Comment: The `Class-Path` in the Manifest is best though. Make sure to separate the different .jar's with a space, not `,` or `;` or anything else.

Comment: @sobolan Interesting. I did not know that -jar ignores CLASSPATH. But what manifest should I put that variable in? The jar file for parsemis?

Comment: @KG `The jar file for parsemis?`. Yes.

Comment: @KG: Yes, the jar file you're running.

Comment: @sobolan ok I updated the manifest in the parsemis jar. I have verified that the new manifest contains the Class-Path setting as described by jonskeet. I still get the same error.

Comment: @JonSkeet any other ideas please?

Comment: @KG: It sounds like you should be able to reproduce this in a short but complete program which basically *just* consists of a `main` method which instantiates one of the types from antlr. You could then post that complete program and the manifest, so we could try to reproduce it.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks a lot for all your help. I was just updating the manifest in the existing jar before, but it appears that creating a new jar altogether works.

Comment: @KG: If you *actually* updated the existing manifest, that should have worked too. I suspect you didn't update the manifest in quite the right way somehow. It's probably irrelevant though, if you've now got a working jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is very old, but I just had exactly the same problem and found this thread.  For posterity, I'm posting how I did eventually get it to run:

As mentioned above, when running with -jar, java apparently ignores the class path.  So don't run it with -jar. instead include the jars in the path and run the class directly.  Poking around, the following should work (paths are on my Ubuntu 12.10 system):

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/antlr.jar:/full/path/to/parsemis.jar de.parsemis.Miner
```

You can then pass in options to the above.  Maye sure you use full paths, and no shortcuts like ~/foo, as they apparently don't expand.

Of course, if you're using a Dot-formatted graph like I am, it dies very early on complaining of "unexpected char 0xA", but at least it gets further.